# find the limit .

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

[image]

**My try**

[image]

But after that I stuck . Can anbody help me .

Please explain me as I am a high school student

Comment: Use Hopital method!

Comment: Related: [A similar but not identical limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1792724/evaluation-of-lim-limits-x-rightarrow-0-frac1x-left12x3x21-x-12x).

Comment: @FrenzyLi thanks it is very useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
(1+3t\pm 2t^2)^{1/t}&=e^{\frac1t \log(1+3t\pm 2t^2)}\\\\
&=e^{3\pm 2t -\frac92 t+O(t^2)}\\\\
&=e^3\left(1+\pm 2t-\frac92 t+O(t^2)\right)
\end{align}$$

Thus, the limit of interest is

$$\lim_{t\to 0}\left(\frac{(1+3t+ 2t^2)^{1/t}-(1+3t- 2t^2)^{1/t}}{t}\right)=e^3\lim_{t\to0}(4+O(t))=4e^3$$

Comment: I could not understand how you have written $e^{3+O(t)}$

Comment: Note that $\log(1+x)=x+O(x^2)$.  So, with $x=3t\pm 2t^2$ we have$$\frac1t \log(1+3t\pm 2t^2)=\frac1t \left((3t\pm 2t^2 )+O(3t\pm 2t^2)^2\right)=3+O(t)$$

Comment: I think you forgot the t in the denominator.

Comment: @Displayname Yes, I did miss that and have edited to correct thanks to your pointing that out!   Much appreciative!  -Mark